# A play with the formal symbol dx

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Today on the first lecture on Spectral analysis I pose a question whether we may make a sense besides this $$\int f(x)\text{dx}$$ expression also of this $$\int f(x) r(\text{dx})$$ expression. Note that by the second I do **not** mean $$\int f(x)\text{d}r(x).$$ The teachre said that he cannot make sense of it, but I think that some analogy (which one is also part of my question) can be made with (infinite) but discrete summation.

Comment: $r(dx)$ and $dr(x)$ mean the same thing...

Comment: how would you prove or at least see this "sameness" ?

Comment: There is nothing to prove, these are just conventional notation.

Comment: But instead of multiplying $r(x)$ with element dx I mean putting it into the argument of the auxilliary function $r(x)$!

Comment: You have to notice that these are just conventional notation. If $r(x)=e^x$, then to see $r(dx)$ as $e^{dx}$ doesn't make sense. The notation $dr(x)$ is common when $r$ is derivable, and if not, the notation $r(dx)$ is commonly used... but there are no rules ! In the case of my example, $r(dx)$ and $dr(x)$ both refer to the measure $e^xdx$.

Comment: Can we consider infinite summation in our case of $r(\text{dx})$ rather then the integration??

Comment: Yes of course ! Take $r$ being the counting measure, i.e. $r(A)=\# A$ for $A\subset \mathbb R$. But as you can see, in this case $r$ is not a function...

Comment: I must ask yet, what is the problem; why $r(x)$ is not a function?

Comment: If $r$ is a measure, both notations $dr(x)$ and $r(dx)$ mean the same. The symbol $dx$ does not having any meaning as an end in itself, it is just a dummy variable and it is probably better to get rid of it when not needed, so, write $\int f$ in place of $\int f(x) dx.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many have commented, $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ is yet another variant notation for what is more often written as $\int f d\mu$ or $\int f(x) d\mu$ or $\int f(x) d\mu(x)$.  Perhaps probabilists use it more often than other people.  Doob's 1952 *Stochastic Processes* uses it.  Theorem 9.1 in Chap. 1 says "... making the obvious notational conventions
$$\mathbf E\{y|\mathcal F\}=\int_\Omega y(\omega')\mathbf P(d\omega', \omega)."$$
Here his $\mathbf P$ is a family of measures, parameterized by the second argument, $\omega$, so for a set $A$ and value of $\omega$, $\mathbf P(A,\omega)$ is a number.

This convention is most useful when one has multiple integrals and more than one possible variable of integration.

As many comments indicate, there is a perverse kind of logic in thinking of $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ as suggesting a kind of Riemann sum, where one adds up rectangles of
height $f(x)$ and base $[x,x+dx)$, weighting each with measure $\mu([x,x+dx))$, finally taking $dx$ as shorthand for the short interval $[x,x+dx)$.

But of course it is just another notational convention, an idiomatic expression in the language of probabalists & other analysts.

Added 3 March 2019:  Dunford and Schwartz use this notation in *Linear Operators, Part 1*, II.2.13, p. 108.

Comment: What about this interpretation: $$\int_a^b f(x)r(\text{dx})=\lim_{\text{dx}\to 0}\sum_{x=a}^b {f(x)\cdot r(\text{dx}})$$

Comment: It doesn't make sense ! Either $r$ is a bounded variation function and $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)(\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k))$ for $\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$ s.t. $\max_i|t_{i+1}-t_i|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty $, or $r$ is a counting measure, and thus $\int_a^b f(x)r(dx)=\sum_{k\in \mathcal D}f(k)r(\{k\})$ for $\mathcal D=\{k\in [a,b]\mid r(\{k\})>0\}$ countable. As **kimchi lover** well explained in his answer, you really have to think $r(dx)$ as $r([x,x+dx])$ for $dx$ very small.

Comment: Notice that if $F$ is increasing, then $F(dx)=F([x,x+dx])=[F(x),F(x+dx)]$ which have length $F(x+dx)-F(x)$ what we commonly write as $dF(x)$... maybe this is a motivation for using $dF(x)$ and $F(dx)$ for the same thing. @user122424

Comment: I'm sorry I really cannot imagine which part of my formula above with $\lim$ makes no sense??

Answer (score 0):

If $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)$ is defined then we can give $f(\mathrm{d}x)$ a quite natural meaning:
$f(\mathrm{d}x) := f'(0) \, \mathrm{d}x.$

Generally, if $f'(x_0)$ is defined then we take $f(x_0 + \mathrm{d}x) := f(x_0) + f'(x_0) \, \mathrm{d}x.$ This is motivated by the *formal* identity
$$\frac{f(x_0+\mathrm{d}x) - f(x_0)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_0) = f'(x_0).$$